# Vue Video Embed Asking for a Typescript file

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue application with typescripts used in it.

I want to use Vue Video Embed (https://github.com/nasa8x/v-video-embed) in my Application.

These are the steps I performed:
#1: `npm install v-video-embed`
#2: `import Embed from 'v-video-embed'`
#3: `Vue.use(Embed);`

**The Issue I am facing is:**
When I use it in my vue component it shows some error messages

**Error#1:**
in my browser console in shows

```
(Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c'))
```

[error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSxQD.png)

**Error#2:**
When I check my root app.ts file it shows up this error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'v-video-embed'. '/home/muhammad/event- 
    star/node_modules/v-video-embed/dist/video-embed.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' 
    type.

    Try `npm i --save-dev @types/v-video-embed` if it exists or add a new declaration 
    (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'v-video-embed';`ts(7016)
```

**I tried these steps but the issue was not fixed:**
I tried to run `npm i --save-dev @types/v-video-embed` command but the types were not found then I tried  to create (.d.ts) files and declare a module **v-video-embed**. after creating (.d.ts) file the **error#2** was gone but I am still facing the **error#1**

Thanks